# tree command supporting wildcards

Tags: windows, tree

Is anyone aware of a 'tree' tool that supports wildcards?

For example, I would like to see all .h and .cpp files in a 'tree' output.

I don't want to use dir /s *.h *.cpp etc - I want to see a tree, not a list of paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004731/output-of-tree-in-command-prompt

```
tree /f /a | findstr /ri /c:"^[^| ]" /c:"^[| ]*[+\\]" /c:"\.h$"
```

Comment: How would you rewrite that line to list *.c *.cpp *.h and *.hpp files?

Comment: `tree /f /a | findstr /ri /c:"^[^| ]" /c:"^[| ]*[+\\]" /c:"\.[ch]p*$"` worked for me, depends how many file extensions you want to add